# How to replace a file uploaded via a form with a file from a URL in node.js express

Tags: javascript, node.js, forms, file-upload, multer

Suppose I usually have files uploaded via a form into my Node.Js app that are stored in the `req.files` array.

I want to replace the first file uploaded with a file available via a URL.

When I try to do this:

```
    const templateFile = await axios({
        url: `http://link.com/to/file.pdf`,
        method: 'GET',
        responseType: 'blob',
    })
        .then(function(response) {
            return response.data
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
            console.log(error)
            return false
        })

    if (!templateFile) return false

    req.files[0] = {
        fieldname: 'uploadedFiles',
        originalname: 'test.pdf',
        mimetype: 'application/pdf',
        encoding: '7bit',
        path: `file:///link.com/to/file.pdf`,
        size: templateFile.length,
    }

    const filePath = req.files[0].path
```

and then

```
 fs.readFile(filePath, function(err, data) {})
```

the `readFile` function cannot get access to that filePath, probably because it's not referring to the server.

How could I replace the file in the `req.files` with the one I have in my URL, so I don't have to change the further logic of the application that checks the size of uploaded files, their type, etc?

Comment: Your code seems to request the file first (via `axios.get`) and then read it once more with `fs.readFile`, which cannot work. But why try both? The question is: what do you want to do with the file afterwards? In other words: What's the code inside the `function(err, data) {}`? Depending on that, it may be better to save the file to your server locally, or consume it directly from the external URL.

Comment: Hey @HeikoTheißen I would like to consume it directly from an external URL but using the `fs` command

Comment: `fs` can only access files, not HTTP resources.